Folland's definition of Tubular neighborhood
Folland states the following proposition:

(Proposition 0.2): Let $S$ be a compact oriented hypersurface of class
$C^k$,$k\ge 2$. There is a neighborhood $V$ of $S$ in $\mathbb{R}^n$ and a number $\epsilon>0$ such that the map $F(x,t) = x+t\nu(x)$ is a $C^{k-1}$ diffeomorhphism of $S\times (-\epsilon,\epsilon)$. $\nu(x)$ is the outer normal to $S$ on point $x$.

I have the following queries regarding this proposition:

Is $F$ a function on $\mathbb{R}^n \times \mathbb{R},\ (S \subset \mathbb{R}^n)$? Because plugging $t=0$, we obtain the entire surface $S$. However point $x$ is given as an input to $\nu$, which doesn't seem right. I think $\nu$ should instead have the parameterized surface values as an input (like in point 2).
It makes more sense to me to define $F : \mathbb{R}^{n-1} \times \mathbb{R}$ to be $F(x,t) = \gamma(x)+t\nu(x)$ where $x = (x_1,\cdots,x_{n-1})$, and $\gamma$ is the parameterization of the surface $S$. In this definition, $t$ is the normal direction and $(x_1,\cdots,x_{n-1})$ represent the tangential direction.

Is definition (2) equivalent to the mapping given in the proposition?

$F$ is a function of $(S \cap U)\times (-\epsilon, \epsilon)$ where $U$ is a small ball of $\mathbb{R}^n$ about some chosen $x_0\in S$. You can't have $\epsilon$ be uniform over the entire $S$, e.g. consider the graph of $\sin(x^2)$ as a "hypersurface" in $\mathbb{R}^2$. If you restrict the domain and $\epsilon$ parameter appropriately, your parametrized map is equivalent, and is in fact a parametrization of $F$.

The book argues that $\epsilon$ is uniform because $S$ is compact.

I missed that detail. It depends on whether $S$ is embedded or merely immersed. If $S$ is embedded then you can have such a diffeomorphism but if it is immersed then you cannot and you must restrict yourself to a neighborhood. Either way, it is assumed that $S\subset \mathbb{R}^n$ that is why the map makes sense.
